# TFS: Keeping a Branch In Synch with its Master

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging

We're using TFS.

I created a branch based off our mainline trunk. I'll be working on a very small portion of the branch. Periodically, I'd like to pull down updates from the mainline trunk and merge them into the branch I'm working on.

I'm using VS 2013. Is this something that can be done in Source Code Explorer? Can someone describe the steps to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:
[TFS reverse integration back to main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14331414/tfs-reverse-integration-back-to-main)

In your case, you would select the Trunk Branch as the source and your development branch as the target.

This will preserve your changes while keeping you up to date with the main branch.

Doing this frequently will make merging back up to the main branch easier when that time comes, as you will have less conflicts to resolve. Also the environment you are testing in will be similar to the main branch environment so it becomes less likely you'll introduce a regression when you merge back into the main branch.